# SQL: Is there a way I can find whether a value is within a specific index range of another value?

Tags: sql, indexing, range

I have two columns filled with mostly 0's and a few 1's. I want to check whether IF a 1 occurs in the first column, a 1 in the second column occurs within a range of 5 rows of that index. So for example, lets say a 1 occurs in column 1 row 83, then I would like to return TRUE if one or more 1's occur in column 2 row 83-88, and FALSE if this is not the case. Examples of this are listed in the code block. I would want to count the number of TRUE and FALSE occurrences.

```
TRUE:  
0   0
0   0
0   0
1   1
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0

TRUE:  
0   0
0   0
0   0
1   0
0   0
0   0
0   1
0   1
0   0
0   0

FALSE:  
0   0
0   0
0   1
1   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   1
```

I have no idea where to begin, so I do not have any code to start with:(

Kind regards,
Kai

Comment: (1) SQL table represent UNORDERED sets.  Without a column specifying the ordering, your question makes no sense.  (2) If you don't have such a column, just delete the question.  (3) If you do, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an ordering column, you can use window functions:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 'false' else 'true' end)
from (select t.*,
             max(col2) over (order by <ordering column>
                          rows between current row and 4 following
                         ) as max_col2_5
      from t
     ) t
where col1 = 1 and max_col2_5 = 1;
```

Comment: I do have an ordering column indeed. Thank you, however isn't a supposed to be b below? You're just naming a without putting it anywhere in your answer..?